# JavaMail 1.5.0 bug or gmail strange issue?

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send emails using a class wrapping javax.mail (JavaMail 1.5.0).
It sends using smtp.gmail.com and it works, but works way too well, since when i send an email with multiple recipients every email is sent (TO+CC) times so if i send an email to 3 recipients i get a total 9 emails (every one repeated 3 times).

This is not good... Setting  Session debug shows the email is correctly sent 1 time with the correct recipients. I'm on jre6u45.

What is the problem? Does anyone have any hint? Have I done a stupid error i'm not seeing?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mailer 
{   
    public static boolean sendMail(
        final String username,
        final String password,
        final String from, 
        final String _tos,
        final String _ccs,
        final String _bccs,
        final String subject,
        final String text,
        final File[] attachments)
    {
        Properties   p           = null;
        Session      s           = null;
        boolean      debug       = true;
        boolean      res         = false;
        boolean      isSecured   = false;
        boolean      isSupported = true;
        String       host        = null;     
        final String charset     = "UTF-8";

        String fromProvider = from.split("@")[1];
        if(fromProvider.compareTo("gmail.com") == 0)
        {
            isSecured = true;
            host      = "smtp.gmail.com";
            p         = System.getProperties();
            p.put("mail.smtp.host",                host);
            p.put("mail.smtps.auth",               "true");
            p.put("mail.smtp.port",                "465");
            p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",     "true");
            p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",  "465");
            p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

            s = Session.getInstance(p, null);
        }
        else {isSupported = false;}

        if(isSupported)
        {
            s.setDebug(debug);

            try
            {
                // init
                MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(s);
                Multipart   mp    = new MimeMultipart();
                InternetAddress[] tos  = {};
                InternetAddress[] ccs  = {};
                InternetAddress[] bccs = {};
                // common
                if(_tos  != null) {tos  = InternetAddress.parse(_tos);}
                if(_ccs  != null) {ccs  = InternetAddress.parse(_ccs);}
                if(_bccs != null) {bccs = InternetAddress.parse(_bccs);}
                email.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO,  tos);
                email.addRecipients(RecipientType.CC,  ccs);
                email.addRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, bccs);

                email.setSubject   (subject, charset);
                email.setSentDate  (Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                // text part
                MimeBodyPart mbpText = new MimeBodyPart();
                mbpText.setText(text, charset, "html");
                mp.addBodyPart(mbpText);

                // attachments
                if(attachments != null && attachments.length > 0)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<attachments.length; i++)
                    {
                        MimeBodyPart mbpAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
                        mbpAttachment.attachFile(attachments[i]);
                        mp.addBodyPart(mbpAttachment);
                    }
                }
                // build elements
                email.setContent(mp);
                email.saveChanges();
                Address[] addresses = email.getAllRecipients();                
                // send
                Transport.send(email, addresses, username, password);

                res = true;
            }
            catch(MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            catch(IOException ex)        {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we don't know what code you are executing it is only possible to make guesses here. Maybe you add the mail in all ReciptentTypes?

```
            email.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO,  tos);
            email.addRecipients(RecipientType.CC,  ccs);
            email.addRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, bccs);
```

I would suggest that you print out the addresses array. If that array contains the mail several times I would start looking where they are added from.

Comment: no, i used "Address[] addresses = email.getAllRecipients();" near the end to check the list of recipients and it's exactly what it should be. I'm using a gmail account to send to other (non gmail) accounts with 2 tos 1 cc and 1 bcc (to other my email test accounts), the debug output shows exactly 4 RCPT TO: but i get 3 emails for each address, bcc is not multiplied. I don't understand "Since we don't know what code you are executing", what informations  are needed to exclude guessing? I'm in trouble trying to debug this, so any suggestion is welcome. I tried email.setrecipients, same result.

Comment: I forgot an important detail: message-ids are identical for duplicated emails. Does anyone have a working and tested (recently) example that can send emails through gmail without duplication? I don't know HOW to seaarch for the problem. Thanks in advance